# Printindex does only work if put at the end

Tags: imakeidx

This minimum example is behaving very strangely on my computer:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\makeindex[name=foo]

\begin{document}
    \printindex %if I delete this line, both indices at the end show up as expected
    %if it is here, there is no index at the beginning of the file
    %and only the foo index shows up after the "content"
    \index[foo]{Some word} asdadas
    \index{Another} asdadas
    \printindex
    \printindex[foo]
\end{document}
```

Problem is, I want the index to be at the beginning of the book. What seems to happen is that the first *printindex* somehow causes the .idx and the resulting .ind file to be empty.

Is this a configuration error or is something wrong in the code I provided?

Comment: `imakeidx` is intended as a one-pass mechanism, so the index data will only be available at the end of the run.  you might try using the `[original]` option (not tested), but i am pretty sure that the simple fact of specifying \makeindex` will cause the `.idx` file to be deleted.  with `[original]`, it will be necessary to run `makeindex` separately, but the deletion of the `.ind` file might be spared.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I conclude from your answer that it is not a configuration issue but indended behavior. Unfortunately, [original] does not work. Is there another package you can recomment which supports multiple indices?

Comment: a quick look at ctan shows the following possibilities: index, `multind`, `splitindex` and `xindy`.  i don't have experience with any of those.  but `imakeidx` is the most up to date, and its author is active in this forum.  i'll poke him and ask him to look at this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have anything producing an index entry after the corresponding `\printindex` command, because the `.idx` file needs to be closed for being processed by MakeIndex.

You can use the `noautomatic` option, but you will need to run manually MakeIndex. If you don't need special formatting for the various indices, using `splitindex` will ease the job.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[splitindex,noautomatic]{imakeidx}

\makeindex
\makeindex[name=foo]

\begin{document}

\printindex

\index[foo]{Some word} asdadas
\index{Another} asdadas

\printindex

\printindex[foo]

\end{document}
```

After running LaTeX on this file, say `taxel.tex`, call

```
splitindex taxel
```

and rerun LaTeX.

Otherwise, you will need to run MakeIndex separately.

You will find some advice in the log file and the console:

```
Package imakeidx Warning: Remember to run (pdf)latex again after calling
(imakeidx)                `splitindex' and processing the indices.
```

for the `splitindex` case and

```
Package imakeidx Warning: Remember to run (pdf)latex again after calling
(imakeidx)                `makeindex taxel.idx'.


Package imakeidx Warning: Remember to run (pdf)latex again after calling
(imakeidx)                `makeindex foo.idx'.
```

for the other case.

Comment: Would there be a problem with having `\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.idx}` just before `\end{document}`?

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes: at that point the `.idx` file has not yet been closed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick you could use if you have a small number of words to index following the `\printindex` command(s).

(I know the question was about a case with the full document following the indexpage, in which case the answer given earlier is a better approach, but I felt it to be useful to present this trick as well.)

I had a (largish) document with one page following the index-pages. On that last page I had two (pst-geo) maps displaying the most important towns in the main document. I wanted those towns to be referenced in the place-names index (along with the references into the main document) .

At some convenient place before the call to `\printindex[places]`, I included the following:

```
\newcommand{\mapspage}[1]{119} % Check and adjust page-number
\index[places]{Amsterdam|mapspage}
\index[places]{Jakarta|mapspage}
```

The page-number (119 in my case) needs to be checked and adjusted by hand, just before the final print run of LaTeX.

Of course, this only works for a small number of `\index` entries on a very small number of pages following the index, but if that's your case, this could do the trick.